# HTML5 multiple pages - different pages and different css

Tags: html, css

What is the best way when you giving css id and class names on HTML elements.

For example:

On my index.html page I will have for example `<section>` element but on the about page I will also have a `<section>` element but it will be in different style(width, background...)

Can I use it like this:
`<section id="about">`

If there is a better way please help.

Comment: `best way` is very relative and depends on your site.

Answer (score 1):

To unequally select element in page use ID (when you have only one element of that kind). To add some properties, add classes for that element

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.red {
  background-color: rgba(250, 20, 20, .3);
}
.blue {
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 250, .3);
}
.long {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">.box</div>
<div class="box red">.box.red</div>
<div class="box long red">.box.long.red</div>
<div class="box long blue">.box.long.blue</div>
```